# Excluded Middle in Gödel's proof of Completeness Theorem

Tags: logic, math-history

What is the “essential use” of the principle of excluded middle applied to infinite collections in Gödel’s completeness proof? Gödel writes:

> [L]et me make a remark about the means of proof used
>   in what follows. Concerning them, no restriction whatsoever has been
>   made. In particular, essential use is made of the principle of the excluded
>   middle for infinite collections (the nondenumerable infinite, however, is
>   not used in the main proof). It might perhaps appear that this would
>   invalidate the entire completeness proof. For what is to be proved can, after
>   all, be viewed as a kind of decidability (every expression of the restricted
>   functional calculus either can be recognized as valid through finitely many
>   inferences or its validity can be refuted by a counterexample). (Gödel 1929, p. 63 in Collected Works Vol. I)

Initially I understood this to refer to the proof of König’s lemma, since the latter uses proof by contradiction (equivalent to excluded middle) to guarantee an adjacent vertex at each step of the construction of the infinite path through the tree.

But Gödel never references König explicitly, and at the point in his proof where the lemma is required, he simply appeals to “familiar arguments” (Gödel, 1930, p. 117 in ibid.)

Is there another (explicit) application of excluded middle to which Gödel could be referring? In particular, is the principle needed to establish that what van Heijenoort calls the “basic alternative”:

> Either, for every n, $A_n$, which is quantifier-free, is truth-functionally satisfiable or, for some n, it is not. (ibid. p. 52)

$A_n$ is a conjunction of the substitution instances $M_1$, $M_2$, …, $M_n$ formed up to the nth level. The nth substitution instance of a formula A is obtained as follows: first instantiate the r-many universal variables of A by the nth r-tuple of integers in some pre-given ordering. Then replace each existential variable by variables $x_i$ indexed by as-yet unused integers in numerical order. The resulting $M_n$ is a quantifier-free, truth-functional formula of propositional logic.

Comment: Can you give a longer excerpt re: "essential use" (for those of us who don't have the collected works on hand)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes. I think this is as much of the quote above that is relevant to the question but I will search for references in the [1930] proof as well.

Comment: Incidentally, I do think at first glance that Godel is referring to Konig's lemma - why does that seem unreasonable? ("Familiar arguments" can include LEM.)

Comment: Van Heijenoort: "To what does "familiar
arguments" refer? A tempting reply is Konig's infinity lemma [...] But throughout 1930 Godel has been meticulous
in giving explicit references. Why assume that he made an exception
for Konig? Perhaps then Godel is referring not to the infinity lemma
itself but to the arguments, viewed as common "folklore", that led to
this lemma." This wouldn't rule out that "essential use of excluded middle" refers to this background argument. But the quote from Godel suggests, to me at least, that he makes *explicit* use of the principle in his own proof.

Comment: The distinction between the lemma itself and the argument leading to it seems a bit over-fine to me here. I really don't see any issue here - it's clear that that step requires LEM.

Comment: One thing I get out of the line "concerning them, no restriction whatsoever has been made" is that Godel is leaving those meta-issues to the interested reader, perhaps in the interest of ease of reading. Given that the interested reader would be able to quickly locate its use in that step, I don't find it surprising that Godel doesn't observe it explicitly.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The distinction I had in mind is the distinction between proving the "Basic alternative" above, and proving Konig's lemma, which is, as I understand it, to prove that if for each n there is a satisfying assignment for $A_n$, then there is a SINGLE assignment that satisfies $A_n$ for every n. To me, the basic alternative comes before Konig's lemma and is seemingly taken for granted in the actual proof.

Comment: @NoahSchweber So excluded middle is used for both steps? I.e., in taking for granted the basic alternative, and in proving Konig's lemma.

Comment: At a glance, **yes**, although I'm certainly not an expert in such things (to put it mildly).